# Definition of power of an ideal, Rees Algebras. And $I^j I^k \subset I^{j+k}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, ideals

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I$ be an ideal of $R.$ Noting that $I^j I^k \subset I^{j+k},$ define a ring structure on the direct sum
> $$\operatorname{Rees}_{R}(I) :=\bigoplus_{j \geq 0} I^j = R \oplus I \oplus I^2 \oplus \cdots .$$
> The homomorphism sending $R$ identically to the first term in this direct sum makes
> $Rees_R(I)$ into an $R-$algebra, called the Rees algebra of $I$. Prove that if $a \in R$ is
> a non-zero-divisor, then the Rees algebra of $(a)$ is isomorphic to the polynomial
> ring $R[x]$ (as an $R-$algebra).

To solve this I need to understand powers of an ideal.
It is generally defined that product of two ideals is the following:
if $I,J$ are ideals of a ring $R$ then $I\cdot J=<ij\;|\;i\in I, j\in J>$
So $I\cdot J$ is generated by all these product $ij$

Then is it true that "in general" for commutative ring $R$ and its ideal $I$ $$I^n=<i_1i_2\cdots i_n\;|\;i_j\in I>$$

So why then we don't have trivially $$I^j I^k = I^{j+k}$$

instead the author has wrote that $$I^j I^k \subset I^{j+k}$$

Answer (score 1):

It's true that $I^j I^k = I^{j+k}$. You don't say who the author is, but perhaps they wrote $I^j I^k\subset I^{j+k}$ to emphasize that if $x\in I^j$ and $y\in I^k$ then $xy \in I^{j+k}$. This is what you need to say that the Rees algebra of $I$ really is an algebra.

For your exercise, here's one perspective. Say that $a\in R$ and $I = (a)$. There is always a unique $R$-algebra map $f\colon R[x]\rightarrow \text{Rees}_R(I)$ sending $x$ to the $a$ in the second summand of $\text{Rees}_R(I) = R\oplus I \oplus I^2\oplus\cdots$, and you need to show that if $a$ is a non-zero-divisor then this is an isomorphism.